# installing emacs 26.3

Tags: install, build

I'm trying to install emacs 26.3 on debian 10. After the download :

```
./configure
sudo make
sudo checkinstall
```

during the checkinstall, I have the following error :

```
 rm -f "/usr/local/share/emacs/26.3/lisp/subdirs.el"
 umask 022; ../build-aux/update-subdirs 
 "/usr/local/share/emacs/26.3/lisp"
 subdir="/usr/local/share/emacs/26.3/site-lisp" ; \
   if [ -f "${subdir}/subdirs.el" ]; then true; else umask 022; 
 /usr/bin/mkdir -p "${subdir}"; (echo "(if (fboundp 'normal-top-level- 
 add-subdirs-to-load-path)"; echo "    (normal-top-level-add-subdirs- 
 to-load-path))") > "${subdir}/subdirs.el"; fi
 subdir="/usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp" ; \
   if [ -f "${subdir}/subdirs.el" ]; then true; else umask 022; 
 /usr/bin/mkdir -p "${subdir}"; (echo "(if (fboundp 'normal-top-level- 
 add-subdirs-to-load-path)"; echo "    (normal-top-level-add-subdirs- 
 to-load-path))") > "${subdir}/subdirs.el"; fi || true 
 [ -z "/usr/bin/gzip" ] || { \
   echo "Compressing *.el etc. ..." && \
   cd "/usr/local/share/emacs/26.3/lisp" && \
   for f in `find . -name "*.elc" -print | sed 's/.elc$/.el/'`; do \
     /usr/bin/gzip -9n "$f"; \
   done; \
   /usr/bin/gzip -9n "../etc/publicsuffix.txt"; \
 }
 Compressing *.el etc. ...
 gzip: ../etc/publicsuffix.txt: No such file or directory
 make: *** [Makefile:571: install-arch-indep] Error 1

 ****  Installation failed. Aborting package creation.
```

How can resolve this issue ?

Comment: Why the checkinstall?  Is this the recommended procedure?

Comment: Also, why use sudo for make? There's no reason not to build as a normal user.

Comment: normally, checkinstall replace make install. But it seems it doesn't worked for this installation ...

Comment: Also happened to me with checkinstall and emacs version 29.0.50. Looks like compression is applied on /usr/local/share/emacs/<version>/etc, and that doesn't exist during checkinstall. Workaround appears to be `./configure --without-compress-install`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This also happened to me with emacs version 29.0.50.

You can use `checkinstall` by the following:

```
mkdir build && cd build
../configure --without-compress-install
make
checkinstall -D --pkgversion 29.0.50
sudo dpkg -i emacs*.deb
```

*Note: The version can be found in `src/config.h`, in the `PACKAGE_VERSION` preprocessor directive.*

This way you may use package management to manage the installed files. However I presume there is a performance disadvantage in not compressing those files as is the default.

I considered using `--prefix` and using `rm -r` on that prefix later, as I'd prefer to build emacs in tmpfs and discard the emacs source tree. However on inspecting the checkinstall built package (with `dpkg-deb -c`) it installs files outside of the prefix into `/usr/share/doc/emacs/`, contrary to what `./configure --help` indicates should happen.

Under the presumption that `--without-compress-install` causes performance loss: unfortunately until the makefiles of emacs are patched it looks like the best way to use and manage emacs is by keeping the source tree around and not using package management via checkinstall. It appears that `stow` has a distinct somewhat overlapping feature-set with package managers like dpkg, as described at [emacswiki.org](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BuildingEmacs).

Comment: To be honest, I don't have test your solution, but it seems more accurate with the question. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You missed a step, after you run the `make` command, you need to run `make install prefix=/replace/with/destination/path`. You also do not need to use `sudo` during the `make` command, but you may have to use `sudo` during the `make install` step depending on where you want to install Emacs.

Comment: You can also `./configure --prefix=/usr/local` (or wherever you wish), and subsequent commands will then use that prefix by default.

Comment: ok thank you, it's worked. But I can't use checkinstall package which allow easy remove of package that are not in the repository ...

Comment: @Kafka You can use the `make uninstall` command though (this will remove all files that were installed).